Are combat sports ethical?
Combat sports inherently involve inflicting harm on another person. Unnecessary harm is ethically wrong, and so combat sports, like those for entertainment, are ethically questionable.

The premise is false: many combat sports do not "inherently involve inflicting harm on another person"; they aim to reach a position where they could. Even in chess, a non-contact game, it is not necessary to actually take the king, only to reach that point.

“Combat sports inherently involve inflicting harm on another person.” It’s worse than that. Violent sports also inflict harm on non-participants: >The impact of mass media violence on aggression has almost always been studied in the laboratory; this paper examines the effect of mass media violence in the real world. The paper presents the first systematic evidence indicating that a type of mass media violence triggers a brief, sharp increase in U.S. homicides. Immediately after heavyweight championship prize fights, 1973-1978, U.S. homicides increased by 12.46 percent. The increase is gr

A sports is not an action, only actions can be ethical or unethical. So the question would have to be about a particular action done as part of the sports. It may sound like nitpicking, but it will lead to a better answer.

A core sports element is competition, which implies being stronger than the other, which implies some level of harm (which implies getting bruises in football, or a depressions in chess), which implies creating scars that are stronger than the original skin. Sports are a controlled war; harm produces a stronger body (what doesn't kill me makes me stronger). So, sports, and making/getting moderate harm in sports is moral and ethical. Remember that political correctness advocates for ZERO HARM, and modern socialism involves a paternal PROTECTION of the WEAK -e.g. victims like LGBT- from harm.

Original Answer
https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/consent

Consent is an essential constituent of a contract and a defense to a tort. However, consent is generally not a defense to criminal charges, with the possible exceptions of rape and sexual assault. In cases of rape and sexual assault, someone's consent is not their true intent if they are under duress or fear.

In combat sport the person consents to the rules of combat and assumes the risk of injury caused by combat within the rules. Combat injuries would be crimes or torts if the person did not consent to combat and did not assume the risk of harm. Public policy excludes some forms of harm from the scope of consent so the rules of combat sports would in theory have to conform to public criminal law.
Combat involves intentional harm, but every possible intentional harm is not allowed within the scope of the rules of combat. Some forms of intentional harm are prohibited under the combat rules or by law. Contact sports involve intentional contact where harm might ensue. A problem of uncertain intention arises in the domain of contact sports and combat sport. The plaintiff would have to claim that harm was done intentionally against the rules of combat or contact sport and thus without consent. The defendant would claim that the harm was caused unintentionally or intentionally but within the scope of consent under the rules. The trier of fact, the judge or jury in the dispute, would have to decide whether there is evidence of wrongful intentional harm. This involves folk psychology concept called mind-reading.
EDIT - Forming Ethical and Moral Judgments - Mindreading Efforts
Demystifying Mindreading for the Law
https://wlr.law.wisc.edu/demystifying-mindreading/

Mindreading is necessary for building complex societies,6 because it is critical for cooperating and detecting deception.7 As one team put it, “mind perception is the essence of morality.”8 The thesis of this article is that mindreading—based on all kinds of stereotypes and cues—is far from magical. It is ordinary and ubiquitous and pervades every area of the law.

Humans observe and contemplate the conduct of other humans. Like Judges and Jurors we form ethical and moral judgments. Public policies passed by Legislatures, and rules of law invented by jurists, are social customs based on judgments that evolve over time. Liberty is a value in a liberal society. To some degree people may be at liberty to engage in conduct with mutual consent that are judged to be unethical or immoral by other members of society.

+1 Same applies to certain forms of kinky sexual role-play where one participant might play someone being sexually abused. Some people might find that gross or sick, but it's not unethical (if only consenting adults are involved). Since mind-reading can be very difficult between good role players, they use a device -- the safeword -- to snap out of the play if needed. Not honoring the safeword could turn the play acting into actual sexual abuse.

Answer would be better without the last sentence. Assessment of mens rea is a standard consideration of all criminal law, and does not require magical powers.

It's not clear to me at all that all activities done intentionally and with mutual consent are ethical.

This seems to be an answer derived from law, not from philosophy. Many legal things are unethical and vice-versa

@g s The term mind reading is common in folk psychology and Theory of Mind (ToM). In that context it does not refer to a magical power but to the effort to attribute states of mind to other persons whose minds we cannot actually read! Philosophers do not study law but the law evolves a pragmatic philosophy in the context of dispute resolution and public policy concerns. This is an article about mind reading in the context of law - Demystifying Mind Reading for the Law - https://wlr.law.wisc.edu/demystifying-mindreading/.

@actinidia - My answer did not claim that all activities done with mutual consent are ethical. Some intentional harms are prohibited by law. Other harms are excluded under the rules of combat or contact sport even if allowed by law. The term: ethical refers to a judgment concerning what is good and how one should act to cause the good. When I was younger (not now) I thought it was good to play hockey; to knock the other guy off his skates; or challenge the other guys to knock me off my skates.  It was bad when an opponent (criminal?) injured my ribs using the butt-end of his hockey stick!

Since the participants understand the rules of the game and these rules are not violated, I do not see anything unethical; an action is not unethical per se, but can be unethical if it imposes harm against another person's will, or if in some way it consists of manipulation against another person's interests.

That "an action is not unethical per se" is arguable. The Platonic Form of the Good, for instance, implies the existence of actions in conflict with Goodness on a basis independent of the will and intention of the person or people involved.
